# ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 nvidia driver conflict

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, nvidia

My notebook is ASUS u36 which has two video cards. One is CPU integrated Intel 3000 and the other is NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M].

When I do not install nvidia driver, there is a problem that the mouse cursor will disappear or appear from time to time.

When I install nvidia driver from Ubuntu's "Additional Drivers", Ubuntu will suspend after it's running a random time. Ubuntu will not accept anything except "Ctrl + Alt + F1" to poweroff or reboot.

When I install nvidia driver downloaded from nvidia's official website. Ubuntu can not display desktop after login.

From Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, this problem always exists. I am not sure whether it exists in 11.10 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I Updated my desktop pc from Ubuntu12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 2 days ago. As soon as finished the upgrade and reboot, my screen "dies". I recived a message system failure can't recognize video card and monitor. 
Working around I note I have a GForce 7025/nForce 630a integrated NVidia card.

Solution: Reboot, and select recovery mode from boot menu. Then graphics safe mode and go to system updates and install the driver.

Hope it helps other begginers as I'm.